# Can I use glScale on GL_POINTS?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, opengl-compat

I am programming a GUI framework in lwjgl (opengl for java). I've recently implemented rounded rectangles by rendering a couple of normal rectangles surrounded by circles. To render the circles I used GL11.GL_POINTS. I now reached the point, where I am trying to implement animations and for a window open animation, I decided to GL11.glScaled() it from small to normal. That works fine, but unfortunately my circles don't get resized.

I tried changing my GL_POINTS circle render method against a method that uses TRIANGLE_FANs and that worked fine. My problem there was, that the circles didn't look smooth and round at all and if I increase the rendered triangles it starts to lag very quick. Even though my computer isn't bad at all.

This is the code I've used to render circles with GL_POINTS.

```java
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
        GL11.glHint(GL11.GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT, GL11.GL_NICEST);
        GL11.glPointSize(radius);
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_POINTS);
        GL11.glVertex2d(x, y);
        GL11.glEnd();
        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
```

This is the code I've used to scale the circles

```java
        GL11.glPushMatrix();
        GL11.glTranslated(x, y, 0);
        GL11.glScaled(2.0f, 2.0f, 1);
        GL11.glTranslated(-x, -y, 0);
        render circles
        GL11.glPopMatrix();
```

I expect the circles to scale accordingly to the number I've put into glScaled()

Currently they aren't rescaling at all, just rendered at their normal size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a demonstration of how to properly render a circle using triangle fans:

```
public void render() {
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();
    // Coordinate system starts out as screen space coordinates
    glOrtho(0, 400, 300, 0, 1, -1);
    glColor3d(1, 0.5, 0.5);
    renderCircle(120, 120, 100);
    glColor3d(0.5, 1, 0.5);
    renderCircle(300, 200, 50);
    glColor3d(0.5, 0.5, 1);
    renderCircle(200, 250, 30);
}

private void renderCircle(double centerX, double centerY, double radius) {
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(centerX, centerY, 0);
    glScaled(radius, radius, 1);
    // Another translation here would be wrong
    renderUnitCircle();
    glPopMatrix();
}

private void renderUnitCircle() {
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    int numVertices = 100;
    double angle = 2 * Math.PI / numVertices;
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; ++i) {
        glVertex2d(Math.cos(i*angle), Math.sin(i*angle));
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Output image:

[image: Output image]

The GL_POINT_SIZE value is actually the size of the point in *pixels onscreen*, not current coordinate units. For that reason your circles were unaffected by GL_SCALE. That's one reason not to use GL_POINTS to render circles. The other (arguably more important) reason being that GL_POINT_SIZE is severely deprecated and unsupported in newer OpenGL profiles.

Comment: Yes, that is very close to the way I used to render circles using the TRIANGLE_FAN. Still though, if the circles are really small they don't look smooth and sharp. Anyways, that was the answer I was looking for, because I didn't know that GL_POINT_SIZE defines the size in pixels on screen. 
Thanks!